# Is it possible to use Flink stream processor in between Akka Streams flows as source and sink?

Tags: stream, akka, apache-flink

I am looking to replace one part of my Akka Streams-based stream processor with Flink. Is it currently possible to use Akka Streams as a source for Flink, and then Flink as a source for Akka Streams in the same codebase?

Current flow with Akka Streams is as follows:

```
 // Kafka Source -> Read Flow involving Azure cosmosDB -> Evaluate Flow -> Write Flow -> Logger Flow -> Sink
  lazy private val converterGraph: Graph[ClosedShape.type, Future[Done]] =
    GraphDSL.create(sink) { implicit builder => out =>
      source.watchTermination()(Keep.none) ~> prepareFlow ~> readFlow ~> evaluateFlow ~> writeFlow ~> loggerFlow ~> out
      ClosedShape
  }
```

Flows above are defined like this:

```
def prepareFlow: Flow[FromSource, ToRead, NotUsed]

def readFlow: Flow[ToRead, ToEvaluate, NotUsed]
```

Now instead of the `readFlow` being an Akka flow, I would like to replace it with a Flink stream processor. So the output of `prepareFlow` would be an input for Flink-based `readFlow`, and output of that would be input to `evaluateFlow`.

Basically, is it possible to do something like this:

```
  prepareFlow ~> [Flink source ->read -> result] ~> evaluateFlow ~> writeFlow ~> loggerFlow ~> out
```

I see that there is a [Flink Akka connector (Sink)](https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/tree/master/flink-connector-akka) in Apache Bahir, but not sure if that could be used with just Akka actors or also streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `prepareFlow` reading from CosmosDB as a custom flink `Source` (by extending a [`SourceFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.html)), and wrap the whole evaluate-write-logger flow as a custom [`SinkFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/SinkFunction.html).

As Flink itself is distributed, then you will integrate an akka-stream into a Flink job, but not vice versa. Main problems I see with this approach is that akka-stream had back-pressure out of the box, but Flink itself is mostly blocking. For example, SourceFunction.run() method requires to have an internal infinite loop producing messages on every iteration, so you have to block there to wait for akka-stream to produce next message there.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: In my use case, `prepareFlow` does some prep, but the CosmosDB lookup will be done in Flink and that will be appended to the local state in Flink. Our main motivation in considering Flink is for using the local state data so that the subsequent reads don't need to go to CosmosDB until needed. Will AsyncI/O be useful in our case? As you mentioned, the data will arrive as a stream from akka stream and Flink will need to call CosmosDB to populate for each incoming stream event.

Comment: Additional question regarding your suggestion to write a custom SinkFunction that combines evaluate+write+logger. Will it be problematic to keep just evaluate in the SinkFunction and the others to continue as flows? Thanks again!